# How do I do this kind of strumming?

Tags: guitar, technique, strumming

I'm kinda new to playing the guitar and I found this video on youtube with tabs:

I was able to learn and play to until the 2 minute mark on the song. But I'm having a hard time trying to 'replicate' the strumming sounds in the first few seconds after the 2 minute mark. According to the tabs, it has muted strings but I still can't make it sound like the one in the video. Is that just pure strumming? Cause it looks like he's barely touching the strings with his strumming hand (like during 2:04 of the video) and its like he's only hitting a few strings while he strums.

Any tips would be appreciated. Sorry if the question seems stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your nail, notice that he has long nails.  You don't need to have it so long in my opinion. The key is to aim the strings with the nail and to use a quick wrist movement to have a some sort of percussion effect. This is similar to a flamenco technique called "rumba", well it would be the first part of the technique.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. It's still quite hard, though. Looks like I have to practice more. Thanks!

Comment: As you move your fingers up plucking the string, you also wind up your wrist to hit the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this and wanted to say it was a "rasgueado", and looking at YouTube videos I still think it is.

However only have a dim recollection of this from a very little classical playing I did 20-odd years ago so could be way wrong.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado

Comment: Hmm. I think you maybe right. After searching for some videos, it does look like "rasgueado".  Difference I noticed is he's just using all his fingers at the same time. Thanks for tip! Not that familiar with strumming patterns so I'm glad I asked here.